# How to override the navigation behavior of a screen in a react navigation drawer?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, navigation-drawer

React Native project using React Navigation v6. I've got a drawer navigator and inside there is a home button. I want to customize the behavior of this button so that no matter where you are in the app when you open the drawer and press it, you go back to the top of the home stack.

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-actions/#reset

I found this in the docs, but I can't figure out how to define it in my navigator, only in a screen component.

Here's the drawer navigator.

```js
export const DrawerNavigator = () => {
    return (
        <NavigationContainer theme={MyTheme}>
            <Drawer.Navigator
                initialRouteName={'HomeTabNav'}
                screenOptions={{
                    drawerLabelStyle: {
                        fontFamily: AppStyleConstants.headerFont,
                    },
                    headerShown: false,
                    drawerPosition: 'right',
                    drawerActiveTintColor: Colors.primary,
                }}
            >
                <Drawer.Screen
                    name={'HomeTabNav'}
                    component={MainTabs}
                    options={{ drawerLabel: 'Home' }}
                />
                <Drawer.Screen name={'FAQ'} component={FaqScreen} />
                <Drawer.Screen name={'Glossary'} component={GlossaryScreen} />
                <Drawer.Screen name={'Preferences'} component={PreferencesTabs} />
            </Drawer.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
    );
};
```

Or, to be more specific, how to I alter this portion

```js
<Drawer.Screen
                    name={'HomeTabNav'}
                    component={MainTabs}
                    options={{ drawerLabel: 'Home' }}
                />
```

to make use of this behavior

````js
import { CommonActions } from '@react-navigation/native';

navigation.dispatch(
  CommonActions.reset({
    index: 1,
    routes: [
      { name: 'Home' },
      {
        name: 'Profile',
        params: { user: 'jane' },
      },
    ],
  })
);
```a
````